# Asyncronously send file over TCP connection

Tags: ios, networking, asynchronous, tcp, large-files

so I'm making an iOS app, but this is more of a general networking question.

So what I have is one phone that acts as the server and then a bunch of phones connect to the phone as the client. Basically it's a game/music sharer.

It's kind of hard to really get into the semantics of it, but that isn't important.

What is important is that the server and client are repeatedly sending each other commands and positions rapidly over a TCP connection, and sometimes the client wants to send the server a music file (4MB usually) to play as the music.

The problem I initially encountered was that when sending the large file, it would hang the sending of commands from the client to the server.

My naive solution was to create another socket to connect to the server to send the file to the server, the server would check the IP of the new socket, and if it has the IP of an existing connection then it would just tie it to that connection, receive the file, and then disconnect the socket.

But the problem with this is that it takes a 1-2 second delay for the socket to connect, and I'm aware that there are man-in-the-middle attacks that can occur.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call your solution naive, this is largely how FTP works, separating data and control paths is a good design pattern in my view.

I wouldn't worry about the man in the middle thing.  If you wanted, you could add a command to the client that it responds to over the data connection with a secret the server supplies, this would let you associate the connections without using the ip addressing.

If the delay is a problem then why not establish both connections at the start, the overhead of a few tcp connections on an operating system is not usually significant.

You could also use the two connections for both commands and data, alternating between them.  Since both the server and client know when a connection is busy they can choose to use the idle one.  The advantage of this is that it will keep both connections busy to ensure they are both known to be working.

You probably should also use a different thread for each socket but I suspect you are doing this since it won't work too well without it.